# Java 8 - How to sum all List element in a Map of Lists

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map of Lists of a particular Object and I want to add all the elements of the lists based on a particular instance variable.

My Object:

```
class Risk{ 
    Integer id, riskValue, totRisk=0;
    String name;

    Integer getId(){
       return id;
    }
    Risk(Object[] result){
         id=(Integer)result[0];
         riskValue=(Integer)result[1];
         name=(String)result[3];
    }
}
```

I get from the Database a List of Arrays of type object:

```
List< Object[] > results=getResults();
```

I use Java 8 to group my Data by ID, because I want to **SUM** by `riskValue` all the objects of type `Risk` having the same `id`.

This is what I do:

```
List<Risk> risks=results.stream().map(Risk::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Integer, List<Risk>> byId=risks.stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Risk::getId));
```

At this point I have all my Risk objects grouped by ID. And I want for each list to sum all the objects by `riskValue` and have the total in the variable `totRisk`

How to compute in the variable `totRisk` the total of the variables `riskValue` in each List?

Note1: **I want to do it using Java 8, I know how to do it using Java 7 and below.**

Note2: Perhaps it's also possible to do it in one go, by not having first to group by ID. What I want to achieve is to sum all the objects with the same ID in the original `List<Object[]> results`. If it can be done with only one statement is even better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to be aware that you can combine `Collector`s. See [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function,Collector)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

```
Map<Integer, Integer> byId=risks.stream.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Risk::getId, Collectors.summingInt(Risk::getRiskValue)));
```

You can also combine it with the first operation:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> byId=results.stream().map(Risk::new).collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Risk::getId, Collectors.summingInt(Risk::getRiskValue)));
```

Note that I assume that you have a method `getRiskValue()` in your class `Risk`, otherwise you have to replace `Risk::getRiskValue` with a lambda expression `r -> r.riskValue` to access the field, however, having getter methods is always recommended.

The result maps from id to total.

---

After reading your question again, I noticed that you actually want to sum up `riskValue` and store it within `totRisk` of *each* (?) `Risk` instance. This is a bit more complicated as it doesn’t fit the common usage pattern:

```
Map<Integer, List<Risk>> byId=results.stream().map(Risk::new).collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(Risk::getId, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.toList(), l-> {
      int total=l.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(r -> r.riskValue));
      l.forEach(r->r.totRisk=total);
      return l;
    })));
```

at this point we really should switch to using `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Risk>> byId=results.stream().map(Risk::new).collect(
  groupingBy(Risk::getId, collectingAndThen(toList(), l-> {
    int total=l.stream().collect(summingInt(r -> r.riskValue));
    l.forEach(r->r.totRisk=total);
    return l;
  })));
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Map<Integer, Integer>  it's a Map of "id":"total" for that id, right?

Comment: last thing: using lambda expression as you wrote above by substituting **Risk::getTotRisk** with **r -> r.totRisk**  is not working to me (it doesn't compile). Is it possible to achieve it with a lamba with no need to create the getter?